# Data output syntax in Webi XI3.1

Tags: business-objects, webi

I am trying to duplicate a detail object from Desktop to its Webi equivalent.

I am familiar with the syntax differences, i.e. using semicolons instead of commas and using `[]` rather than `<>` to enclose references to other dimensions/measures/detail objects.

Given the working formula from the Deski report:

```
=ToDate(7+"/1/"+<Current FY>-1 ,"mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I tried to convert this using the syntax I know from Webi:

```
=ToDate(7+"/1/"+[Current FY]-1 ; "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

I faced the error message

> The expression or sub-expression at position 8 in the '-' function uses an invalid data type

I am guessing this has something to do with trying to convert a date datatype into an integer in order to subtract "1." However, I do not know what kind of function this requires.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is [Current FY] a string?

Comment: @Joe no, it's a date returned as a number, given by this:

= If (MonthNumberOfYear(CurrentDate())<7) Then Year(CurrentDate()) Else Year(CurrentDate())+1

We figured out that one by using FormatNumber:

=ToDate("07/01/"+FormatNumber(([Current FY]-1); "0000"); "MM/dd/yyyy")

and that ended up working.

Comment: @AmandaA Could you please flag your question as answered by adding the solution mentioned? That way, it won't keep showing up as unanswered. Thanks.